# Facebook Publish Object issue via opengraph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to publish my object using Facebook Open Graph. I am using the sample code from FB .

I am not unable to understand the error code thrown by Facebook, and it does not seem to documented as well. It would be great if somebody can point me in the right direction.

```
{
   "app_id":642296222485XXXX,
   "url":"\"http:\/\/samples.ogp.me\/649325335115XXX\"",
   "title":"\"Sample Badge\"",
   "image":"\"https:\/\/fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net\/images\/devsite\/attachment_blank.png\"",
   "description":"\"\""
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the application in the Graph API Explorer to your application. The request are being made by the application "Graph API Explorer", not your app and hence the error is thrown.

[image]